# Download Sharepoint Lists Using Python

Tags: python-2.7, list, sharepoint, download

I am trying to download sharepoint list using python code. and I am getting 401 unauthorized error. 
     Here is the sample code :

```
import urllib2
from sharepoint import SharePointSite, basic_auth_opener
auth_handler = urllib2.HTTPBasicAuthHandler()
auth_handler.add_password(realm='CDI Application',
                          uri='http://teams.abc.com/sites/test/sitename',
                          user='domain/abcde',
                          passwd='#####')
opener = urllib2.build_opener(auth_handler)
site = SharePointSite(site_url, opener)
for sp_list in site.lists:
    print sp_list.id, sp_list.meta['Title']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try modifying your code to use the basic_auth_opener class instead.

```
uri='http://teams.abc.com/sites/test/sitename'
opener = basic_auth_opener(uri, 'domain/abcde', '#####')
site = SharePointSite(site_url, opener)

for sp_list in site.lists:
    print sp_list.id, sp_list.meta['Title']
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Thanks.